# How to put "</script>" in a javascript string?

Tags: javascript, html, string

I've been trying some tricks in javascript and came to a ridiculous problem: *I can't use `<script>` as a substring in a javascript string!* Here is an example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            alert("<script></script>");
        </script>
    </head>
</html>
```

It supposed to print out **`<script></script>`**, but instead, I get this:

```
");
```

Printed out on the page, as HTML.

***Question:*** How can I use `<script>` followed by `</script>` substrings in Javascript, and why is it acting that way?

Here is [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wp4z6brL/) of it.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

What's tripping you up is the `</script>`. The HTML parser doesn't recognize Javascript strings or nested `<script>` tags, so it's interpreting that as the closing tag for the initial `<script>`. That is, this part of the document is parsed as:

```
<script>                (open tag)
    alert("<script>     (text node - contents of the script)
</script>               (close tag)
");                     (text node - plain text)
```

The second `</script>` is ignored, as there's no other `<script>` tag for it to close.

To work around this, break up `</script` so that the HTML parser doesn't see it. For instance:

```
alert("<script><\/script>");
```

or:

```
alert("<script><" + "/script>");
```

or just put the code in an external Javascript file. This issue only arises for inline scripts.

Answer (score 3):

it is because of the `\` I believe. i have no concrete explanation since I am a newbie to Javascript but this code should work:

```
alert("<script><\/script>");
```

came up with it using Java knowledge.. Haha since the `\` is an escape key in many languages.

Answer (score -1):

Alert(`\<script>\</script>\`)

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.