# Put code directly in popup window function

Tags: javascript, html

For example, I have this script

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
var myWindow = window.open("", "myWindow", "width=200,height=100");
myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'myWindow'</p>");
myWindow.opener.document.write("<p>This is the source window!</p>");
}
</script>
```

Instead of

```
 myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'myWindow'</p>");
```

I would want to put something like

```
 myWindow.document.write("<script> alert("h");</script>");
```

Due to circumstances, I cannot link to another page with the code in it. Putting the script makes the window not even open. Thanks

Comment: Just do `"<script> alert('h');</script>"`? Your problem is that you need to escape h or use a different set of quotation marks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to put "</script>" in a javascript string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28259389/how-to-put-script-in-a-javascript-string)

Comment: The problem is neither work.

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Comment: You need `myWindow.opener.document.close()` at the end AND escape the / `<\/script>`

Comment: What is that for though? Without the script it works perfectly but when i put it in it doesn't

Answer (score 1):

1. quotes
2. close the document (`myWindow.document.close()`)
3. escape the `</script>` you cannot have `</script>` inside script tags.
4. NEVER document.write into an already rendered page

Something like this

```js
function myFunction() {
  var myWindow = window.open("", "myWindow", "width=200,height=100");
  myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'myWindow'</p>");
  myWindow.document.close();
  var p = document.createElement("p")
  p.innerHTML = "This is the source window!";
  myWindow.opener.document.querySelector("body").appendChild(p); // same as document.querySelector("body") 
}
```

If you want to use script, you need to

```
var myWindow = window.open("", "myWindow", "width=200,height=100");
myWindow.document.write("<script>alert('h')<\/script>"); // MANDATORY ESCAPE \/SCRIPT
myWindow.document.close();
```

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't really answer my question. The code works fine with text but once i put a script into it, it breaks. How would you put a script in the opened window?

Comment: Your use case is unclear. What do you need to have in the child window and what in the parent window?

Comment: Look at my question. I want to put a script in the popup window.

Comment: Look at my answer. You need to escape the end  /script tag

Comment: OK I see it now. If i put a full webpage in there do I have to end all tags like that? Right now instead of the button it just says [Object Object]

Comment: Only the </script> tag

Answer (score 0):

Instead of double quotes wrap your content into single quote

```
myWindow.document.write('<script> alert("h");</script>');
```

Comment: Doesn't work, just writes it in plaintext next to the button.

Comment: Try to add this method reload script Working example - `(function (){
    var w = window.open();
    w.document.write('<script> alert("h");</script>');
})();`

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand your code. What does it mean/do/ how do I use it?

Comment: You cannot have `</script>` inside script tags.

Comment: @mplungjan Where did you find that in `myWindow.document.write('<script> alert("h");</script>');`

Comment: You do not when you run from console of course. But he isn’t