# Invalid token when echoing PHP value in JS

Tags: javascript, php

I echo a PHP value into a JavaSript string, like this:

```
var x = '<?php echo addcslashes($_GET['value'], "'") ?>';
```

It works just fine, but when I set `$_GET['value']` as `"><script>alert('hi')</script>` for example, I got:

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token**

In DevTools, the string looks properly escaped, but is not, because it halts the rest of JS code.

```
var x = '"><script>alert(\'hi\')</script>';
```

Comment: The contiguous characters `</script>` cannot exist in an inline Javascript `<script>` tag. Consider inserting the data through `data-` attributes, or (worse) ajax, though you could also concatenate the parts on either side of the `</script>`

Comment: Maybe because you have an extra '>' in front of your <script> tag?

Comment: @CertainPerformance interresting and understandable behaviour. The browser doesn't know what kind of script language it is, so `var x = '</script>'` could be something else than a string, from the browser point of view? You should post it as answer

Comment: FYI: Using `<\/script>` works, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28259389/how-to-put-script-in-a-javascript-string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The contiguous characters `</script>` cannot exist in an inline Javascript  tag. The HTML markup is parsed before the Javascript, and `</script>` in the HTML markup after the start of a `<script>` tag indicates the end of that tag.

You can concatenate instead, so that, for example, your text would result in

```
var x = '"><script>alert(\'hi\')</scr' + 'ipt>';
```

by using `str_replace`:

```
$withSlashes = addcslashes($_GET['value'], "'");
$xContent = str_replace('</script>', "</scr' + 'ipt>", $withSlashes);
...
var x = '<?php echo $xContent ?>';
```

But it would be preferable not to dynamically construct Javascript code. Consider using data attributes instead, and to separate the Javascript into its own separate file, eg

```
<script
  src="script.js"
  data-x="<?php echo addcslashes($_GET['value'], "'") ?>"
></script>
```

(if you use this method, remember to properly escape `"`s if they can exist in the result)