# JSON throwing an error when it has a script tag embedded with the json

Tags: javascript, html, json

Here is my script for testing purposes

```
<script>
var json = {
     "html": "<h3>COVID-19 Visitor Declaration</h3><script></script>"
};
</script>
```

That will throw a javascript error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

Now if I change the script to something else the error goes away

```
<script>
var json = {
     "html": "<h3>COVID-19 Visitor Declaration</h3><scripta></scripta>"
};
</script>
```

How can I let that script tag go through as valid JSON, guessing this is something to do with security.

Comment: its not json, its an object literal. https://stackoverflow.com/q/28259389/17447

Comment: thanks that made sense, so real issue is that the html parser gets confused when it sees the script although it is in a string. Interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to update your code to:

```
<script>
    var json = {
        "html": "<h3>COVID-19 Visitor Declaration</h3><script><\/script>"
    };
</script>
```

Escaped tag </script> is most important for that.

Comment: But then why does the <scripta></scripta> work?

Comment: Because it doesnt get interpreted as script? @rukiman As soon as you put up script tags, your browser expects javascript. Using a different tag like <scripta> is nothing different than using an image tag for example. its not "reserved"

Answer (score 0):

By using the `Escape` characters, for your closing  tag `<\/script>`

```js
var json = {
  "html":  "<h3>COVID-19 Visitor Declaration</h3><script><\/script>"
};


document.getElementById("html-content").innerHTML = json.html;
```

```html
<div id="html-content"></div>
```

`<scripta>` works because it's not a valid tag for the browsers to evaluate and thus render it as normally on DOM.

When you pass `<script>`, browser parse it a valid HTML tag

```js
var json = {
  "html":  "<h3>COVID-19 Visitor Declaration</h3><scripta>Test</scripta>"
};


document.getElementById("html-content").innerHTML = json.html;
```

```html
<div id="html-content"></div>
```